# How to make content dragable inside a ScrollRect in Unity 4.6?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

When using the ScrollRect to implement a scroll view, you force the mobile user to scroll on the background, because as Unity states in [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/Manual/script-ScrollRect.html)

> To scroll content, the input must be received from inside the bounds of the ScrollRect, not on the content itself.

How can you make scrolling user friendly by making content scroll?

Answer (score 4):

You can do so:

Implement  IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IDragHandler

```
public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    _parentScroll.OnBeginDrag(eventData);
}

public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    _parentScroll.OnEndDrag(eventData);
}
public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    _parentScroll.OnDrag(eventData);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! :D
To future readers: please note that ALL of the three methods need to be implemented to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

I've made this script to solve that issue, content scrolls the view as expected. Just add it to the each element inside the ScrollRect content.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ScrollElement : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler
{

    ScrollRect scrollRect;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        scrollRect = GetComponentInParent<ScrollRect> ();
    }

    public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        scrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition -= eventData.delta.y / ((float)Screen.height);
    }
}
```

Note that on the `Awake` it will try find the first `ScrollRect` component. **Beware** that if the object itself (`this`) contains the component `GetComponentInParent<ScrollRect> ()` will use that one.

Comment: If you have a loop adding this ScrollElement component or adding elements to the scrolling panel, you can instead have OnDrag raise an event `public event EventHandler<EventArgs<PointerEventData>> Drag;`. That event could be attached to a handler in the same component adding loop. The event handler would have the same logic as your OnDrag. The benefit is only the loop needs a reference to the parent scrollRect. Not every scroll-able element.